# How can I uppercase a hashed md5 in my query?

Tags: sql, node.js, passport.js, md5

How can I uppercase a hashed md5 before it goes into the database?

I tried the following:

```
connection.query("UPDATE penguins SET password = UPPER(password)");
```

This works, but it does not uppercase the user that just registered. It does uppercase every other md5 hash in the database.

This is my INSERT query:

```
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO penguins (moderator, registrationdate, inventory, email, password, username, nickname ) VALUES ('" + moderator + "','" + registrationdate + "','" + inventory + "','" + email +  "', + MD5('" + password + "'), '" + username + "', '"+username+"')";
```

This is my whole passport strategy:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var datetime = moment().format('x')
var mysql = require('mysql');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});

connection.query('USE kitsune');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM penguins WHERE id = " + id, function(err, rows) {
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });


    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

       passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'username',
        passwordField: 'password',
        gameusernameField: 'username',
        nicknameField: 'nickname',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, username, password, done) {

        // here you read from req
        const email = req.body.email
        const nickname = req.body.nickname
        const inventory = '%1'; // This is what the user gets on register. You can set this to anything that you want like: %1%2%3%4%5%6%7%8%9%10%11%12%13%14%15%16
        const moderator = '0';
        const registrationdate = datetime

    passport.serializeUser(function(username, done) {
        done(null, username);
    });

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `penguins` WHERE `username` = '" + username + "'", function(err, rows) {
            console.log(rows);
            console.log("above row object");
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
            } else {

                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUserMysql = new Object();
                newUserMysql.registrationdate = registrationdate;
                newUserMysql.moderator = moderator;
                newUserMysql.inventory = inventory;
                newUserMysql.email = email;
                newUserMysql.password = password; // use the generateHash function in our user model
                newUserMysql.username = username;
                newUserMysql.nickname = nickname;
                var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO penguins (moderator, registrationdate, inventory, email, password, username, nickname ) VALUES ('" + moderator + "','" + registrationdate + "','" + inventory + "','" + email +  "', + MD5('" + password + "'), '" + username + "', '"+username+"')";
                console.log(insertQuery);
                console.log('Query is rolling!');
                connection.query(insertQuery, function(err, rows) {
                    newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;
                    return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    });

            }
        });

    }));





    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, email, password, username, nickname, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `penguins` WHERE `username` = '" + username + "'", function(err, rows) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (!rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
            }

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!(rows[0].password == password)) return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, rows[0]);

        });



    }));

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried UPPER() at insert statement, hope this may work.

```
    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO penguins (moderator, registrationdate, inventory, email, password, username, nickname ) VALUES ('" + moderator + "',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'" + inventory + "','" + email +  "', + UPPER(MD5('" + password + "')), '" + username + "', '"+username+"')";
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Do you also know if: registrationdate is set right etc in here?

Comment: your question is not clear for registrationdate, if you want to set date for registration at insert query you can use any one of these NOW(), CURDATE(). If this is not your question please tell me more.

Comment: It needs to be in UNIX time but it's not updating itself in database

Comment: I tried something like
const dateTime = new Date().getTime();
const timestamp = Math.floor(dateTime / 1000);

const registrationdate = timestamp
newUserMysql.registrationdate = registrationdate;

This works, but it doesnt update the time and the time that gets inserted is always the same.

Comment: I believe UNIX_TIMESTAMP() would help me, how do I add this into my query?

Comment: Hi here is the sample for UNIX_TIMESTAMP() http://rextester.com/CLLHE18858, I hope you can use it at insert query.